# VS: Update Service Reference creates requirement for "Global" prefixes in Reference.vb

Tags: vb.net, web-services, entity-framework, wcf

VB 2012
WCF & EF 6.1*

I have a client and a web service. When I recompile/change the WS, I go back to my client, and '*Update Service Reference*'. Works like a charm-except, the resulting Reference.vb in the client complains that any classes that were defined from the server have a Global. prefix; To be precise, the error description is:

```
Error   9   Type 'serverNamespace.CountryName' is not defined.
C:\...\UpdateServiceReference\Reference.vb
```

...where *UpdateServiceReference* is the client side proxy.

```
Public Interface IUpdateService
[...]
    <System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://...", ReplyAction:="http://.../IUpdateService/GetClientCountriesResponse")>  _
    Function GetClientCountries(ByVal placeHolder As Boolean) As serverNamespace.CountryName()
[...]
End Interface
```

This service reference/proxy on the client only imports from system stuff and the server's namespace's entities. My only settings/imports at the top of the compiler-created Reference.vb are:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
```

But here is the really strange (well, confusing) part. In order to clear out the generated errors in the Error List:

> **Type 'serverNamespace.CountryName' is not defined. Change 'serverNamespace.CountryName' to
>   'Global.serverNamespace.CountryName'.**

I need to do as the compiler suggests above, and change (in Reference.vb) any line with something like this:

```
Function GetClientCountries(ByVal placeHolder As Boolean) As serverNamespace.CountryName()
```

...to...

```
Function GetClientCountries(ByVal placeHolder As Boolean) As Global.serverNamespace.CountryName()
```

---at EVERY place in both class body & interface... And everything works!

How can I decorate my Web Service to just make it work?

I've already tried using all kinds of "Imports" in the WS code, but nothing has any effect... And just stupidly adding a Global prefix to the existing WS code won't compile...